# How to pop CupertinoPageRoute with swipe down?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm using the following Code to get a FadeInTransition from the bottom when opening the page.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  CupertinoPageRoute(
    fullscreenDialog: true,
    maintainState: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Routines(),
  )
)
```

Normally in iOS you can just swipe left to close the current page. Is there an easy way to swipe down to `pop` the current page or do I have to implement a custom field with a `GestureDetector()`?

The goal is to have a closing transition like in the GIF below using a swipe down at the top

[image: Fade Out Transition]

I considered using a `DraggableScrollableSheet` but I don't want to slide the Page into view from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it with an `DraggableScrollableSheet`:

```
onPressed: () {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Routines();
    },
  );
},
```

and Wrapping my new Page with:

```
return DraggableScrollableSheet( //TODO make same for Entries
      expand: false,
      initialChildSize: 1.0,
      minChildSize: 0.8,
      builder: (context, scrollController) {
        return Page2();
      }
);
```